# Suggestions to start a cross-platform project

Tags: cross-platform

I have a big project in my head, it should be cross-platform (Win, Max and Linux), online (Client - Server) and with 3D graphics. I would like some suggestions to start with the right things.

Currently I'm a PHP/MySQL coder, I used to code in C and Pascal on DOS ages (Borland Times ;)), my C knowlegde need a refresh but it's ok.

I guess C++ it's the right language. What platform and what i should use to code? I can choose from all three platforms. My idea was to use Visual Studio 2010 C++, but i'm not sure if it support Native code.

What kind of libraries should i use? I guessed OpenSSL for the login, OpenGL for graphics part. For the Audio or the GUI?  Any other suggestions are well accepted.

I know it's a "BIG DEAL" but I have no rush and it'll be a free-time project, only for my pleasure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your opinion on Mono/Java? Do you want to support mobile devices as well?

Comment: Never tried... But for what I know the performance on 3D aren't good as C++. I don't need mobile devices support.

Comment: Doesn't warrant an full answer; but make sure you **choose** which platforms you are targeting up-front (which you have); once you are done with that don't start messing about with stuff that doesn't apply to those platforms - e.g. you shouldn't need to worry about endianess (at least with modern Mac): don't start writing a game that can run (in theory) on ANYTHING.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/195/any-tips-for-creating-cross-platform-games

Comment: It sounds like you're biting off more than you can chew.  Going from "no game dev experience" to "cross platform online game" is too big a leap.  I would start with something simpler.  Download Unity and play around with that.  Make a mod of a pre-existing game.  Pick one platform, make it work, then rework it to make it cross platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My game setup (a multiplayer persistent game) can run on Windows and Linux (the client doesn't but it is more of a configuration thing than a code thing).

I use MySQL and TinyXML on the server side.
I had to do some tweaking with: sockets, criticalsections, timers, threads and text (ie. 4bytes widechars and different syntax of wsprintf).
It compiles on MSVC (C++) on my Windows development machine, on Ubuntu with gcc for the 'live' server.

The client also uses TinyXML, sockets, criticalsections, threads and timers and also Irrlicht for the rendering (Irrlicht is the 3D engine and is cross platform: Win,Linux & MacOS).

C++ is probably the way to go if you want to tie together a big project, I'd advice OpenGL too as it is widespread, cross platform and quite good.

Just out of curiosity, what will the game be about?

ps. oh, old Borland 4.52, I remember that one :-)

Comment: The game isn't a true game, something like second life but easier and less cluttered. I had some game dev experience but they are limited to DOS using allegro library (oh, it was cool and fun ;) )

Comment: Allegro with/by DJgpp ? Remeber that one anyway :-) PS. I started out with a 2D world and switched when the networking started to work so I didn't bite off too much at the start.