# Best Way To Develop Robust Cross-Platform Application?

Tags: windows, cross-platform, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any tips for creating cross-platform games?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/195/any-tips-for-creating-cross-platform-games)

Windows C programmer here (going back to 1992 and Windows95 back when it was called Windows93). Can function in C++, but mostly still a C programmer.

Looking to build a cross-platform casual game. Very numbers heavy with only a few artistic embellishments and animations, so perhaps a development environment for business apps might be the best option. Or an easy-to-use 2D game dev platform.

Target platforms: Windows, Mac, MS Tablet, iPhone, iPad, Android.

I currently develop on Windows with Visual Studio 2012, but we could spend up to $50K on hardware/software/middleware if necessary. Not very competent getting open-source software working. Would rather pay the money and jump right into app development.

Recommendations?

Comment: you can try SDL, SFML.

Comment: @Gajoo Neither of your suggestions support "MS Tablet, iPhone, iPad, Android" which is over half of the OP's target platforms.

Comment: Personally I suggest Unity3D (http://unity3d.com).

Comment: @ClassicThunder I know at least has SDL support for all of them, the only thing it does not support is "Windows Phone" which can not be blamed since that OS doesn't let you run a C/C++ code. also SFML is on it's way to have complete ports for both iOS and android, but they are not complete yet. (a google search will help)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do something with C or C++, I would personally recommend using OpenGL with GLFW (and toss in GLEW if you plan on using OpenGL 2 or higher functions). GLFW and GLEW work well with Visual Studio 2012 and other compilers.

However, if you aren't interested in creating your own engine with OpenGL, and are willing to use c#, you could use XNA with MonoDevelop, which should work on all or most of your target platforms.

Comment: the guy wants to create a casual 2d game with little art and you're recommending OpenGL... come on

Comment: I'm just saying that if he wanted a cross platform game in C that he could try OpenGL, but if that's not what he's looking for I would recommend XNA which is cross-platform (unofficially).

Answer (score 0):

[Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) lets you stick with C++ and Visual Studio for development but gets you running on Windows, Mac, iPhone, iPad, and Android with little fuss.  MS tablet is trickier since you'll probably use C# and XNA for that.